# Find if A is invertible for all $\alpha$

Tags: matrices

[image]

I end up with two solutions but I should only have gotten one ($\alpha=2$).

Did I do something wrong? I repeated it two more times but I end with the same outcome. Please help!

Comment: Confirming correct solution is $\alpha=2$ as the [determinant of the matrix is $3(\alpha-2)^2$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+of+%7B%7B1,0,3,1%7D,%7B2,-1,6,3%7D,%7B-3,3-x,-9,4x-12%7D,%7B1,2-x,x%2B1,3x-5%7D%7D).

Comment: Going from the matrix in the top right to the first matrix in the second row, what happened to the fourth row-second column entry?  It appears as though you confused yourself as to which row was being modified, and you were originally trying to modify the third row but forgot while you started the fourth thinking that it was also being modified.  A suggestion, write down your elementary row operations, including which row is being changed.  It makes your work easier to follow as an outsider and helps keep your thoughts organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&3&1\\0&-1&0&1\\0&3-\alpha&0&4\alpha-9\\0&2-\alpha&\alpha-2&3\alpha-6\end{pmatrix}$

Apply row operation $R_3-R_4\mapsto R_3$

$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&3&1\\0&-1&0&1\\0&1&-(\alpha-2)&\alpha-3\\0&\color{red}{2-\alpha}&\alpha-2&3\alpha-6\end{pmatrix}$

You replaced the red $2-\alpha$ instead with $-1$ for seemingly no reason.

From here you might continue with the operations $R_2+R_3\mapsto R_3$ and $(2-\alpha)R_2+R_4\mapsto R_4$ to get

> $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&3&1\\0&-1&0&1\\0&0&-\alpha+2&\alpha-2\\0&0&\alpha-2&2\alpha-4\end{pmatrix}$

Its just a stones throw away to complete row reduction at this point where you'll find the determinant to be $3(\alpha-2)^2$.  The original matrix will not be invertible when the determinant is zero and will be invertible otherwise.